# Is it possible to create a tree structure with classes as its node?

Tags: java, class, tree, nodes

I am trying to implement a custom tree structure in java. I want my tree to have its nodes of type class (i.e.,) each node in my tree should represent a class and should point to its child nodes.
Is this possible to create? If not, is there any other way of implementing such a structure?

P.S. sorry if the question seems illogical :-|

Comment: You can try using the `Class` type to store classes in nodes. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap the `Class` objects to be able to point to their children.

```java
class CustomTree {
    Node root;

    public CustomTree(Node root) {
        this.root = root;
    }
}

class Node {
    Class value;
    List<Node> children;

    public Node(Class value) {
        this.value = value;
        children = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addChild(Class clazz) {...}
}
```